# Executing one function multiple times simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I have a Python script with a simple function. I would like to run this function 2 times, simultaneously and was wondering if this was possible.

script.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def func1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Finished sleeping')


t1_start = time.perf_counter()
p1 = Process(target=func1())
p1 = Process(target=func1())

t1_stop = time.perf_counter()

print("elapsed time: {} sec".format(round(t1_stop - t1_start), 1))
```

Given output:

```
Finished sleeping
Finished sleeping
elapsed time: 2 sec
```

Expected output:

```
Finished sleeping
Finished sleeping
elapsed time: 1 sec
```

I have also tried this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def func1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Finished sleeping')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1_start = time.perf_counter()
    p1 = Process(target=func1)  # note no ()
    p2 = Process(target=func1)  # note no ()

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    t1_stop = time.perf_counter()

    print("elapsed time: {} sec".format(round(t1_stop - t1_start), 1))
```

However that gives this output:

```
elapsed time: 0 sec
Finished sleeping
Finished sleeping
```

Comment: ``Process(target=func1())`` *executes* ``func1`` immediately. Use ``Process(target=func1)`` instead. Note that you must ``start`` processes and should ``join`` them to see how long they run, by the way.

Comment: Please take a look at the [mutliprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Your system requires you to use an ``if __name__ == "__main__":`` guard for starting the processes. As the error says.

Comment: Re, "...simultaneously..." FYI, threads and processes do not, in and of themselves, provide _guaranteed_ simultaneity. They provide [_concurrency_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)), which is a weaker/broader concept. Concurrent tasks are _allowed_ to happen at the same time, but not guaranteed to happen at the same time. If you ever write a program where it actually is important for A and B to happen simultaneously, then you probably will need to run it on a [_real-time operating system_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) to provide that guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `target=func1()` calls `func1` and passes its return value (in this case `None`) as the target argument for `Process` instead of passing the function `func1` itself.
- `Process(...)` just creates a `Process` object. You never really spawn/execute any of the created `Process` objects. You need to add a call to `.start`. Depending on the OS (ie if `os.fork` is used to spawn the new process), this will also require us to add `__main__` guard (which is a best-practice anyway regardless of the used OS).
- You are using `p1` twice.

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def func1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Finished sleeping')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1_start = time.perf_counter()
    p1 = Process(target=func1)  # note no ()
    p2 = Process(target=func1)  # note no ()

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    t1_stop = time.perf_counter()

    print("elapsed time: {} sec".format(round(t1_stop - t1_start), 1))
```

This gives the output

```
elapsed time: 0 sec
Finished sleepingFinished sleeping
```

which makes sense. If the function is executed 2 times in separated processes then the main process, the main process would not execute `time.sleep(1)` at all.

However, if we add `.join()` then the main process will be forced to wait for the child processes:

```
p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Now the output is the same as your required output:

```
Finished sleeping
Finished sleeping
elapsed time: 1 sec
```

EDIT: If you want an arbitrary number of processes with a loop:

```
...
times = 3
processes = []
for _ in range(times):
    p = Process(target=func1)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
...
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to include this... it does not work @DeepSpace

Comment: They also missed the ``__main__`` guard.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Works for me without `__main__` guard

Comment: @DeepSpace That's system dependent. It fails with the [spawn start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), which is the default on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Nice, didn't know about this. I'll add `__main__` guard to the answer for future generations (it's a best practice anyway)

Comment: @EdenHikri See updated answer with updated code and explanation)

Comment: I have updated my question to show that this doesnt work either unfortunately. @DeepSpace

Comment: @EdenHikri Seems like you didn't add `.join` as the last part of the answer suggests

Comment: My apologies, this works great! Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a for loop? I can elaborate if necessary @DeepSpace

Comment: @EdenHikri Yes, I've added a way to achieve that with a loop